# url rewriting : How to rewrite 2 urls with same number of parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've created some url rewriting rules.

It works fine.

But i have 2 pages with urls like that :

actualites.php?id=xxx& alias=xxx

--> Result : id-alias.php (ex : 1-article_name.php)

equipe.php?id=xxx& alias=xxx

--> Result : id-alias.php ((ex : 1-article_name.php)

These 2 pages are different, not the same design, etc.

I would like to rewrite these 2 different pages. My question is how to have two different rules for these 2 urls.

Since they have 2 parameters, i have only one rule applied (the first one)

```
#become : 1-alias.php
RewriteRule  ^([0-9]*)-(.*)\.php$ actualites.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [L]

#become : 1-alias.php
RewriteRule  ^([0-9]*)-(.*)\.php$ equipe.php?id_equipe=$1&alias=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to add code in `actualites.php` that first checks whether the parameter values for "cat" and "alias" are valid, then you can't.

If you want to code that into `actualites.php`, check if the parameters are valid, and if not, send the params to `equipe.php` as "id_equipe" and "alias". Otherwise you'll need to add something to the URL to validate which request you're actually mapping to. For example:

```
http://yourdomain.com/a/1-article.php  -->  /actualites.php?cat=1&alias=article
http://yourdomain.com/e/1-article.php  -->  /equipe.php?id_equipe=1&alias=article
```

Without that `/a/` or `/e/`, there's no way to tell what to map to. If you don't use something like that, you'll need to do all validation in your php.

Comment: I've thought about adding something to the URL and as you confirm this solution, i will use it. Thanks.