# .htacess How to rewrite 2 urls with same number of parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thank you everyone in advance.

I have 2 URLS with the same number of parameters lets say:

1) www.yourdomain.com/blogs.php?h_id=1&blog_id=6

and

2)www.yourdomain.com/page.php?h_id=5&page_id=9

how do i go about writing an rewrite rule that will rewrite both the url's.

& yes i have read the Stuff mentioned on
[url rewriting : How to rewrite 2 urls with same number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963206/url-rewriting-how-to-rewrite-2-urls-with-same-number-of-parameters)

But i havent got the desired output.
Please help it would be of great help.
Thank you again.

Comment: How do you want to rewrite them? What is desired output?

Comment: www.yourdomain.com/1/6... Thank you for the reply...

Comment: You cannot have the same for both url. All is said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963206/url-rewriting-how-to-rewrite-2-urls-with-same-number-of-parameters

Comment: There has to be another way... Something that would help me figuring out a solution for this issue....

Comment: Well you could have **www.yourdomain.com/blog/1/6** and **www.yourdomain.com/page/1/6**

Comment: Sure would do that thanks... i figured out the rule..
.RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /page.php?h_id=$1&page_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /blogs.php?h_id=$1&blog_id=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For separate page's you can use for this example URL *http://www.yourdomain.com/blogs/1/6*

```
RewriteRule blogs/(\d+)/(\d+) /blogs.php?h_id=$1&blog_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule page/(\d+)/(\d+) /page.php?h_id=$1&page_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```